# Composer require block with like OR operator

Tags: php, composer-php, gd, imagick

There is possible to set Composer for `require` block to check if some PHP extension is installed with something like `OR` operator?

For example:
I prepare some package for image manipulation based on PHP, it's works with GD or Imagick library.

How to prepare composer.json file to require at least one PHP image extension?

Comment: No: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/751

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Composer: Require at least one dependency or another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095385/php-composer-require-at-least-one-dependency-or-another)